# How to improve performance of port scanner executed on page load

Tags: php

I have this small function for detecting a visitors port. The problem is that it's far too slow. It increases the page load time by about 3 seconds; naturally this is unacceptable.

Can anybody improve upon this for a better page load time?

```
function ipProxyPortCheck($ip){
    $timeout = 1;
    $ports = array(80,3128,8080);
    $flag = 0;
    foreach($ports as $port){
        @$fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,$timeout);
        if(!empty($fp)){
            $flag = 1;
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}
```

Comment: Even though you're not exactly new, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take care to always properly indent your code samples. (No indenting is regarded as *lacking indentation*, not as indenting consistently with zero spaces ;) ). Note that I have removed the "thanks" part, you don't need to add it to further posts.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?  Can it be offloaded to a background task?  Can you use an ajax request after the page is loaded to run the port scanner?

Comment: It's used to detect if a visitor has come from a bad source (proxy/automated).

Comment: This code is unlikely to work over the Internet. Is this for a LAN application or something?

Answer (score 2):

This code cannot be improved in the general case except by reducing the timeout value. If your visitor does not respond at all when you attempt to connect to them the full timeout interval will need to elapse before you determine that they are unconnectable.

Other than that, an improvement you can make is to add `break;` when you do connect successfully, so that you don't attempt to connect to the other ports as well (no need to). But this will only play a role when the visitor is connectable in the first place.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @AlexWhinfield: Example of what?

Comment: @AlexWhinfield: After the `fclose`. But that should really have been obvious.

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @AlexWhinfield: That was not unexpected. Please take the time to read the answer, it's all of 6 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the timeout. [fsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) accepts a float as timeout which is the timeout in seconds.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @AlexWhinfield Do you know how to approach the documentation and understand it?

Answer (score 0):

> I have this small function for detecting a visitors port. The problem is that it's far to slow. It increases the page load time by about 3 seconds,naturally this is unacceptable. Can anybody improve upon this for a better page load time?

First of all: do it *once* per IP, and store the result for consecutive requests. Then, you can decrease the timeout to, say, half a second (use `$timeout = 0.5`). Then, make sure you return from the function as soon as one of the ports is open, which will decrease the time waiting, as it then checks the least possible amount of ports. Lastly, I would recommend logging which port was open for a while, to determine which ports are most likely to be open. You can sort your `$ports` accordingly. So, if port `80` has a higher probability to "be open" than `8080` or `3128`, make sure it comes first.

```
function ipProxyPortCheck($ip){
    $timeout = 0.5;
    $ports = array(80,8080,3128);
    foreach($ports as $port){
        if((@$fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,$timeout)) !== false) {
           fclose($fp);
           return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not paralllelllize the three portscans?

Comment: @bzlm Could you provide an example?